# How do I reorder rows in a CSV file by referring to a single column?

Tags: python, csv

In Test1.csv, in all strings after the second line of the Entry column, I would like to write a code that sorts all the lines of Test1.csv according to the order of the Entry column in Test2.csv.
I would appreciate your advice. Thank you for your cooperation.
This is a simplified version of this data (more than 1000 lines).

```py
import pandas as pd

input_path1 = "Test1.csv"
input_path2 = "Test2.csv"
output_path = "output.csv"
df1 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=input_path1, encoding="utf-8")
df2 = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=input_path2, encoding="utf-8")
(df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='Entry')
    .set_index('Entry')
    .drop('Number_x', axis='columns')
    .rename({'Number_y': 'Number'}, axis='columns')
    .to_csv(output_path)
```

#### Error massage

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "narabekae.py", line 28, in <module>
    .drop('Number_x', axis='columns')
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4102, in drop
    errors=errors,
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3914, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3946, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "/Users/macuser/downloads/yes/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5340, in drop
    raise KeyError("{} not found in axis".format(labels[mask]))
KeyError: "['Number_x'] not found in axis"
```

#### The output what I want

```
,V1,V2,>sp,Entry,details,PepPI
1,OS=Ha,MTNKG,>sp,A4G4K7,HFQ_HERAR,7.028864399
2,OS=Sh,MAKGQ,>sp,B4TFA6,HFQ_SALHS,7.158609631
3,OS=Oi,MAQSV,>sp,Q8EQQ9,HFQ_OCEIH,9.229953074
4,OS=Bc,MAERS,>sp,A9M5C4,HFQ_BRUC2,8.154348935
5,OS=Re,MAERS,>sp,Q2K8U6,HFQ_RHIEC,8.154348935
```

#### Test1.csv

```
,V1,V2,>sp,Entry,details,PepPI
1,OS=Re,MAERS,>sp,Q2K8U6,HFQ_RHIEC,8.154348935
2,OS=Sh,MAKGQ,>sp,B4TFA6,HFQ_SALHS,7.158609631
3,OS=Ha,MTNKG,>sp,A4G4K7,HFQ_HERAR,7.028864399
4,OS=Bc,MAERS,>sp,A9M5C4,HFQ_BRUC2,8.154348935
5,OS=Oi,MAQSV,>sp,Q8EQQ9,HFQ_OCEIH,9.229953074
```

#### Test2.csv

```
pI,Molecular weight (average),Entry,Entry name,Organism
6.82,8763.13,A4G4K7,HFQ_HERAR,Rat
6.97,11119.33,B4TFA6,HFQ_SALHS,Pig
9.22,8438.69,Q8EQQ9,HFQ_OCEIH,Bacteria
7.95,8854.28,A9M5C4,HFQ_BRUC2,Mouse
7.95,9044.5,Q2K8U6,HFQ_RHIEC,Human
```

#### Additional information

macOS10.15.4 Python3.7.3 Atom

Answer (score 0):

To reorder the columns, you just define list of columns in the order that you want, and use `df[columns]`;

```py
In [17]: columns = ["V1","V2",">sp","Entry","details","PepPI"]

In [18]: df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='Entry')

In [19]: df[columns]
Out[19]:
      V1     V2  >sp   Entry    details     PepPI
0  OS=Re  MAERS  >sp  Q2K8U6  HFQ_RHIEC  8.154349
1  OS=Sh  MAKGQ  >sp  B4TFA6  HFQ_SALHS  7.158610
2  OS=Ha  MTNKG  >sp  A4G4K7  HFQ_HERAR  7.028864
3  OS=Bc  MAERS  >sp  A9M5C4  HFQ_BRUC2  8.154349
4  OS=Oi  MAQSV  >sp  Q8EQQ9  HFQ_OCEIH  9.229953
```

Naturally, you can save it normally with the `to_csv()` method:

```py
df[columns].to_csv(output_path)
```

#### Notes

- The errors are not reproducible with the data given, since there are no `Number` columns in the dataframes `df1` and `df2`.
- You should not `set_index("Entry")` if you want to have it saved in the `.csv` in the middle (since in the "The output what I want" you have simple integer based indexing).